# from XYZ import * -- pyCharm not seeing it (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, pycharm

This code executes fine from within the client's test framework:

from XYZ import *

However, when trying to setup a pyCharm project to navigate the code, it only sees module XYZ if **init**.py files are stored at every level from the sources folder*** to the module folder.

***< sources folder >/path/to/module/XYZ.py

The sources folder is:
(a) included in the PYTHONPATH environment variable
(b) set as a sources root in pyCharm
(c) added to the paths in the project's interpreter settings

Somehow the test framework is able to find it since it executes the test scripts fine, but pyCharm can't find it unless I create package **init**.py files and then update the import statement to:

from path.to.module.XYZ import *

What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 2018.2.4